# IE9, tables, and display: block

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

For the low-width mobile version of my site, I switch the `display` of certain `table`, `tr`, `td`, and `th` to `block`, to let them stack vertically. I use this as a technique to allow wide tables to continue to display all of their content without overflowing outside of their container.

It works perfectly in all of the modern 5 browsers, but does not work in IE9.  Is there a way to do this there?

Here is a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfCzD/4/

Here are screenshots

**IE11** (Goal):

[image: ie11]

**IE9** (Bad result):

[image: ie10]

Comment: Did you look at your fiddle in IE (since it has the correct DOCTYPE)

Comment: I did.  I'm trying it in "IETester" and it's giving me the wrong result. The screenshot is from the jfiddle.

Answer (score 11):

## http://jsfiddle.net/xnKTH/

```
td {
    width: 100%\9;
    float: left\9;
}
```

Add a width on the TD and float it.

Comment: Exact same problem, perfect copy-paste-able solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some useful links (if you haven't already checked them out):

1. [CSS Tricks: Responsive Data Tables](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)
2. [CSS Tricks: Complete Guide to the Table Element](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use div tags for table

e.g:

```
<div style="display:table">
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      content content
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      content content content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this will work excellent for ie8+

Comment: This would be a big headache to manage.  The inline styling would have to be overwritten with !important directives.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: i use inline styles only for example, better to write class for every style

Comment: I see.  Still, avoiding the use of the proper tags for legacy support feels very "wrong" to me.  Upvoted answer, but not accepting.